# How to remove the white gap between navbar and headear?

Tags: html, css

I just want to know to remove the white gaps that is before and after the header.
If possible can you edit my code
btw I am just a begginer and haven't written this code. I copied spome from W3Schools.

This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .auto-style2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1 style="background-color:MediumSeaGreen;" class="auto-style2">The Logic Store</h1>

  <margin: 0px;>

</body>

<margin: 0px;>

</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="navbar" style="height: 45px">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown" style="height: 45px">
    <button class="dropbtn">Phones
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple</a>
      <a href="#">Samsung</a>
      <a href="#">Google</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown" style="height: 45px">
    <button class="dropbtn">Laptops
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple</a>
      <a href="#">HP</a>
      <a href="#">Dell</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#about">About</a>

</div>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>

<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see there is a gap before the header and one that is inbetween the header and the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example you provided you have to assign css to the h1 tag. Otherwise the user-agent styling will take precedence.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .auto-style2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1 style="background-color:MediumSeaGreen;" class="auto-style2">The Logic Store</h1>

  <margin: 0px;>

</body>

<margin: 0px;>

</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="navbar" style="height: 45px">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown" style="height: 45px">
    <button class="dropbtn">Phones
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple</a>
      <a href="#">Samsung</a>
      <a href="#">Google</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown" style="height: 45px">
    <button class="dropbtn">Laptops
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Apple</a>
      <a href="#">HP</a>
      <a href="#">Dell</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#about">About</a>

</div>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>

<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```